# django test case client.get got empty response

Tags: django

I have following django(1.7) view unit test

```
from django.test import TestCase

class PersonTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['person.json']

    def test_get_person(self):
        response = self.client.get('/person/1/')
        print "content", response.content
        print "context", response.context
        #self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

However I always get empty response.content and None response.context.

If I try the following in django shell

```
c=Client()
response = c.get("....")
```

response.content and response.context are correct.
Already spent couple of hours on this, and totally have no idea.

Comment: how is your fixture folder? are you sure that this json is in the correct place? and when you run your test? what happens? Because the console should show a message saying something like "xx fixtures loaded"